# Is there a minimum size for UICollectionView or a bug in iOS 9 beta?

Tags: xcode, autolayout, uicollectionview, ios9

I have a very strange auto layout issue that I’ve never run into before. I’m not sure if it is a bug or I’m doing something silly.
First off this is with Xcode 7 beta 5 and running on the iOS 9 simulator.
The desired look is for a toolbar to be shown at the top with a couple buttons in it (one of which only appears when needed) and a collection view that fills the remainder of the screen as seen below:
[image]

I have constraints to keep the toolbar against the top, left, and right edges as well as touching the collection view below it. The collection view in addition to the 0 point distance to the toolbar above it has 0 point connections to the bottom, left and right edges of the view.

What I actually get however is two notices in the console that there are constraints that can’t be simultaneously satisfied. The constraints that get broken are shown below along with all of the constraints that get listed but they are the height of the toolbar and the 0 point spacing between the toolbar and collection view.
[image]

The notices list all the constraints that are involved in the problem followed by the constraint it will break to make things work (it always picks the wrong one…):

```
    "<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x7fbaf9fd0e20 V:[_UILayoutGuide:0x7fbaf9fd9b40(20)]>",
    "<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x7fbaf9fc94c0 V:|-(0)-[_UILayoutGuide:0x7fbaf9fd9b40]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7fbaf9fd9450 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fbaf9d3f8d0 'toolbarHeight' V:[UIToolbar:0x7fbaf9d3f6f0(44)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fbaf9fda8a0 'toolbarToCollectionView' V:[UIToolbar:0x7fbaf9d3f6f0]-(0)-[UICollectionView:0x7fbafa84c000]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fbaf9fa67e0 'toolbarTop' V:[_UILayoutGuide:0x7fbaf9fd9b40]-(0)-[UIToolbar:0x7fbaf9d3f6f0]>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7fbaf9d4ac90 h=-&- v=-&- 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Top' V:|-(0)-[UIView:0x7fbaf9fd9450]   (Names: '|':UITransitionView:0x7fbaf9fd91d0 )>"


Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 

<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fbaf9d3f8d0 'toolbarHeight' V:[UIToolbar:0x7fbaf9d3f6f0(44)]>


    "<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x7fbaf9fd0e20 V:[_UILayoutGuide:0x7fbaf9fd9b40(20)]>",
    "<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x7fbaf9fc94c0 V:|-(0)-[_UILayoutGuide:0x7fbaf9fd9b40]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7fbaf9fd9450 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fbaf9fda8a0 'toolbarToCollectionView' V:[UIToolbar:0x7fbaf9d3f6f0]-(0)-[UICollectionView:0x7fbafa84c000]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fbaf9fa67e0 'toolbarTop' V:[_UILayoutGuide:0x7fbaf9fd9b40]-(0)-[UIToolbar:0x7fbaf9d3f6f0]>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7fbaf9d4ac90 h=-&- v=-&- 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Top' V:|-(0)-[UIView:0x7fbaf9fd9450]   (Names: '|':UITransitionView:0x7fbaf9fd91d0 )>"

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fbaf9fda8a0 'toolbarToCollectionView' V:[UIToolbar:0x7fbaf9d3f6f0]-(0)-[UICollectionView:0x7fbafa84c000]>
```

Given that both sets of constraints list `NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint` I added the following code to attempt and stop extra constraints from being added, it had no effect…

```
collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
toolbar.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

If I set the view itself to not translate autoresizing mask into constraints and all that appears is black (but the collection view does get created, but buried somewhere).

the issue seems to be the `NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint` but I can't figure out how to make it go away.

Is this all from a bug in the beta? Is there some strange minimum collection view size (it seems like the collection view is a screen hog)? Or am I missing something (likely something super obvious)?

I got the first image by forcing the collection view to have the proper frame size in `viewDidAppear()` but once the collection view is scrolled down a ways it breaks free of the frame and takes the whole screen.

If I debug the view hierarchy the toolbar does in fact show up behind the collection view so it is getting drawn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears this is a bug, the workaround is to delete every constraint from all of the views and create the proper constraints in code and add them to the primary view. This swap has to happen in `viewDidAppear` as the trouble makers don't appear before that.